# How to remove unwanted mark seams

Tags: uv

[image]

Can you anybody tell me how can I delete these mark seams please? In edit mode I can't find any mark seams but when I unwrap the model there they are! why? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - not working.

Answer (score 2):

Those are pinned UV coordinates, they are not affected by future unwraps.

Select them and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to unpin. Unwrap afterwards.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_editing.html